# textview overlapping in relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I m having a Custom List for a chat application.

It has basically Two imageView in the either side and textView for the "chat message" in the middle.
Below all the three above there is textview for time at the bottom.
The screenshot below would better suffice.

The problem here is the time textView is overlapping over the imageView if the text of the "chat message" is only line.

This problem is better corrected with html-css as float clear:both.

I went through another answer for this with a nested RelativeLayout within LinearLayout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355808/android-relative-layout-below-2-items) but i want to keep it clean with a single RelativeLayout.

The layout xml is as below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msgText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
    android:text="this is a test" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40px"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/msgText"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The screenshot for this as below -

[image]

Comment: i don't see any screenshot...

Comment: may be some prob with your browser. Here - http://i.stack.imgur.com/lAWim.png

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

> android:layout_below="@+id/msgText"

Change to this:

> android:layout_below="@id/icon2"

**EDIT**

Put a minHeight on your message TextView which is equal to the image height and don't change as I told you above.

Comment: then it is overlapping with the msgText if that is multi-line. Either way it is overlapping with something.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LinearLayout` instead

The layout example which avatar on the **left** side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="content here"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="date here"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout example which avatar on the **right** side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:text="content here"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="date here"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```